# How to add a for loop in a DirectX 10 project?

Tags: c++, for-loop, directx, directx-10

Before I ask for help, I would like to mention that I am very new to DirectX and yes, I do know how to code in C++. But I'm getting errors when I try to complete my homework.

The homework assignment is simple. Draw a circle (using a minimum of 20 triangles) and put a texture on the circle. No problem. But I have to create the vertices using a For loop. This is what I have so far:

```
double x = 0.1;
double y = 1.0;
double z = 0.5;
double xin = 0.3;
double yin = -0.1;

// Create vertex buffer
SimpleVertex vertices[] =
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, zf),
        XMFLOAT3(xf, yf, zf),
        XMFLOAT3((x+xin)f, (y+yin)f, zf),
    }


};
```

I haven't finished adding all the code I want to make the circle. It's more of a test run. But I get an error on my for loop. It doesn't seem to want to read the for, expected an expression. I tried putting the For loop outside of SimpleVertex and it works. 
How would I add a for loop to make my circle?
Thanks for helping the noob.
I would wait for office hours, but it's Labor day and I've been at it all weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your `for` loop in a declaration, which you cannot do. You need to declare `vertices` first, then initialise it with `for` loop:

```
int main()
{
    // Declare your vertices:
    const auto maxVertices = 20;
    SimpleVertex vertices[maxVertices];

    // Initialise the vertices in a for loop
    for (int i = 0; i < maxVertices; ++i)
    {
        vertices[i].Position = /* calculate position */
    }
}
```

It's likely you'll use `i` to calculate one of the positions, something like:

```
vertices[i].Position = { i * x, y, z };
```

Comment: The three lines in the for block are no effect, it should be something like `vertices[i].member = value;`